# Monaca上でURLからの音声データを再生する方法

Tags: javascript, monaca

DocomoAPIの音声合成APIを使用しようと考えているのですが、moancaでアプリの開発が可能でしょうか。その場合、audioオブジェクトからPhoneGapのMediaオブジェクトに変換する必要がありますか。または、他に何か良い方法がありますでしょうか。

どうかご教示頂けないでしょうか。よろしくお願いいたします。